# Default values of arguments in C++ constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, default-value, initialization-list

Can I specify default values at once like in METHOD 1 or should I use overloaded constructor like in METHOD 2 or with initialization list like in METHOD 3/4?

Which method is better/right way and why (all of them seems to work)?

And what is the difference between METHOD 3 and 4 - should I specify first constructor declaration, and then next definition outside class or can I at once specify definition?

**METHOD 1:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const string GLOBAL_VAR = "XXX";

class Object
{
private:
    string var;

public:
    Object(string inArg = "yyy")
    {
        this->var = GLOBAL_VAR + inArg + "ZZZ";
    }

    string show()
    {
        return this->var;
    }
};


int main() {
    Object o1, o2("www");
    cout << o1.show() << endl;
    cout << o2.show() << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

**METHOD 2:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const string GLOBAL_VAR = "XXX";

class Object
{
private:
    string var;

public:
    Object()
    {
        this->var = GLOBAL_VAR + "yyyZZZ";
    }

    Object(string inArg)
    {
        this->var = GLOBAL_VAR + inArg + "ZZZ";
    }

    string show()
    {
        return this->var;
    }
};


int main() {
    Object o1, o2("www");
    cout << o1.show() << endl;
    cout << o2.show() << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

**METHOD 3:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const string GLOBAL_VAR = "XXX";

class Object
{
private:
    string var;

public:
    //declaration:
    Object();
    Object(string);

    string show()
    {
        return this->var;
    }
};
//definition:
Object::Object() : var(GLOBAL_VAR + "yyyZZZ") {}
Object::Object(string inArg) : var(GLOBAL_VAR + inArg + "ZZZ"){}


int main() {
    Object o1, o2("www");
    cout << o1.show() << endl;
    cout << o2.show() << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

**METHOD 4:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const string GLOBAL_VAR = "XXX";

class Object
{
private:
    string var;

public:
    //declaration and definition in one:
    Object() : var(GLOBAL_VAR + "yyyZZZ") {}
    Object(string inArg) : var(GLOBAL_VAR + inArg + "ZZZ") {}

    string show()
    {
        return this->var;
    }
};


int main() {
    Object o1, o2("www");
    cout << o1.show() << endl;
    cout << o2.show() << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: In C++, you don't need the `this->` notation.  Access the member variables directly.

Comment: There's really no difference between method 2 and 3. And the only difference between method 2 and 4 is that one uses initializer lists while the other does not. That means methods 2, 3 and 4 are the same. As for which is "best", that's up to what you think, it's subjective and a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider both approaches to be equally valid. Depending on the particulars of each individual class, each approach has its advantages, strengths, and weaknesses.

Using a default value would typically be the best choice when the object needs to be initialized pretty much the same way, whether or not the constructor parameter gets defaulted. Specifying a default value prevents the need to duplicate a bunch of code. You only have one constructor.

On the other hand, using overloaded constructors makes it possible to cleanly construct the object in completely different way, depending on whether the parameter is given or not. Forcing the class to have a single constructor typically results in carpetbombing the code with a bunch of `if` statements, in this case.

Also, don't forget about the third option: a delegating constructor. Using the class in your example code:

```
Object() : Object("")
{
}
```

This approach has its own inherent advantages too.

There is no consensus on which approach is best, in general. It's best to consider the individual requirements of each class, and choose the approach that works best for that class. What's best for one class may not be the best way for another class.

Comment: According to a delegating constructor, which one is better: `Object(string inArg="yyy") : var(inArg) { var = GLOBAL_VAR + var + "ZZZ"; }` or `Object() : Object("yyy") {} Object(string inArg) : var(inArg) { var = GLOBAL_VAR + var + "ZZZ"; }` ?

Comment: For this specific case, I believe that the delegating constructor approach is better, at least with the compiler I use. But just for this specific class. This conclusion would only apply to this particular class, and no other class. In other words: it's of very little value; and this should not be interpreted to mean that a delegating constructor would be better in some other class, or with a different compiler. Knowing, and understanding each one of your classes' usage, and your compiler, is required in order to reach the right conclusion on this topic for a given class.